# Converting docker run to docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to convert my docker run command, but I cannot get it working. This is the docker run command I use and works well

```
sudo docker run -d \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml \
  -v $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.localhost \
  -l traefik.port=8080 \
  --network traefik-proxy \
  --name traefik \
  traefik --docker
```

And this is the compose file I built:

```
version: "3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik-2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:monitor.localhost"
      traefik.port: "8080"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik-proxy
```

The problem is that when I use docker-compose, the proxy seems to be working, but when I access the monitor site (monitor.localhost), it gives me a 404 not found. I have double checked everything, but I just can't figure it out what is wrong with the compose file. I tried to get into the shell of the container to see if it looks alright, but apparently Alpine based Traefik image doesn't have bash, or even sh.

Comment: be aware the difference between `$PWD` and `.`. The first one refers to the path you enter the command, the last one refers from the `docker-compose`-file. It is import e.g. when you run `docker-compose -f path/to/docker-compose.yml up`. 
*Otherwise:* The only difference I see is that you don't transfer your parameter `--docker` to your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wie already pointed out in the comments, you're not passing the `--docker` flag in your `docker-compose.yml`. Try it like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:monitor.localhost
      traefik.port: 8080
    command: ["--docker"]

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik-proxy
```

Comment: Thank you. That did work. The command, and the file structure in general. I tried to alter mine, it didn't work, but it worked after I coped from your answer.